# chart js does scroll into left hidden area when scrolling from right side

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js, nuxt.js, vue-chartjs

with, nuxtjs and chartjs, I made horizontal scrolling.
when I write style="float: left" in candle-stick-chart plugin tag, I can scroll to right area.
but on the other hand, with style="float: right" does not let me scroll to left area.
I'm wondering why it occurs.

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": " myNuxt.js project",
  "author": "test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --fix pages/**/*.{js,vue}",
    "precommit": "yarn lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.15.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^0.7.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-chartjs-financial": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vue2-transitions": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^0.5.1"
  }
}
```

plugins/candle-stick-chart.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Candlestick, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs-financial'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

Vue.component('candle-stick-chart', {
  extends: Candlestick,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
})
```

pages/test.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container fluid>
      <b-row align-v="end">
        <b-col sm="12">
          <b-row>
            <b-col sm="12">
              <b-card class="rounded-0">
                <b-card-body>  
                  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
                    <candle-stick-chart :chart-data="datacollection" :options="options"  class="walking-speed-chart" style="float: right"/>
                  </div>
                </b-card-body>
              </b-card>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      datacollection: {},
      options: {}
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.fillData()
    this.fillData2()
  },
  methods: {
    fillData () {
      console.log(this.generateRandomChartData())
      this.datacollection = {
        labels: ['1/1','1/2','1/3','1/4','1/5','1/6','1/7',
            '1/8','1/9','1/10'
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'OHLC',
            data: this.generateRandomChartData(),
            yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
          },
          {
            label: 'line',
            data: ['0.155','0.118','0.121','0.068','0.083','0.060','0.067',
            '0.121','0.121','0.150','0.118','0.097','0.078','0.127',
            '0.155','0.140','0.101','0.140','0.041','0.093','0.189',
            '0.146','0.134','0.127','0.116','0.111','0.125','0.116'
            ],
            type: "line",
            yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    generateRandomChartData (initial = 1000, count = 10, changeRange = 100) {
      let o = initial; let h; let l; let c; let t = new Date('2001-01-01').getTime()
      return [...Array(count)].map((_, i) => {
        o = c || o
        h = o + (this.randomChange(changeRange) / 2)
        l = o - (this.randomChange(changeRange) / 2)
        c = o + (this.randomChange(changeRange) - (changeRange / 2))
        t += (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        return {
          o, h, l, c, t
        }
      })
    },
    generateRandomData (initial = 1000, count = 10, changeRange = 100) {
      let o = initial; let t = new Date('2020-01-01').getTime()
      return [...Array(count)].map((_, i) => {
        t += (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        return {
          o, h
        }
      })
    },
    randomChange (range = 100) {
      return Math.random() * range
    },
    fillData2 () {
      this.options = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            id: "y-axis-1",   
            position: "left", 
            }, {
            id: "y-axis-2",
            position: "right",
          }],
        },
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
<style>
  .chartAreaWrapper {
       width: 80%;
       overflow-y: hidden;
       overflow-x: scroll;
  }

  .walking-speed-chart{
       margin-top: 20px;
       height: 1000px;
       width: 1200px;
  }
</style>
```